# IOS 14 Emoji Keyboard does not resize the window in browser

Tags: html, ios, browser, vuetify.js

I just upgrade my IOS to 14 and with that I have a new emoji keyboard. I have a comment box fixed at the bottom as shown in the first photo below

[image]

**===========================================================================**

But when I click the emoticon button on the keyboard. It will hide some part of the textarea. I felt like the window did not resize with the keyboard. As shown in the photo below:

**===========================================================================**

[image]